# List templates strange behavior after upgrade to 2010

Tags: list-template

We upgraded our MOSS2007 to MSS2010 (database attach upgrade method). When we save a library as a template and create a new library based on that template, it works. 
However, when we add documents to the new library, they are NOT displayed. No filters, sufficient (admin) permissions, no checked-out files. The View all site content shows correct number of documents in the lib, the explorer view shows the documents, but the standard Sharepoint view displays no files. Neither does a new view.
Help would be appreciated :).
Thank you,
Ravie.

Update: it occurs only when we set a library to contain both minor and major versions and then use it as a template. If we save it including content, the original content is visible, but not the new content (e. g. when a user uploads a new document).

Comment: Any custom content types in play on this library?

Comment: Hi James,
no custom content types.

Answer (score 1):

This is reproducible in my cleanly installed SharePoint 2010 system.

It is not related to the upgrade.

Comment: Thank you, Steve. I will submit a support ticket for MS.
Ravie.